# How to convert video file to string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video, signalr, video-processing

I am working in signalR, i want to send a video file from one client to another client by splitting video file in different parts.
I had already sent images by splitting image src data and received that on another client.

```
    document.getElementById("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
        function readImage() {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var FR = new FileReader();
                FR.onload = function (e) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function () {
                        var imageString = img.src.toString()
                        var spliceStr = "";
                        var i = 0;
                        while (i < imageString.length)
                        {
                            spliceStr = imageString.substring(i, (i+50000));
                            ImageSpliceArray.push(spliceStr);
                            i = i + 50000;
                        }
                        $("#imageId").html('<img src="' + img.src + '"/>');
                        testR.server.hello("Start", imageString.length,"");
                        testR.server.hello("FragmentCount", ImageSpliceArray.length,"");
                        for(k=0;k<ImageSpliceArray.length;k++)
                        {
                            testR.server.hello("FragmentData", ImageSpliceArray[k], k);
                        }
                        testR.server.hello("Done", "", "");
                    };
                    img.src = e.target.result;

                };
                FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        }
```

Now I want the same thing for video. I read a video from `input type ="file"`. Then I know to put that video in html video element, but I want the video all data in string format to send that video to another by splitting that string in different parts.

Note:SignalR is used to send text from one client to another client. Having data size approximately(50kb).

Comment: So why not read just 50 000 bytes from source video file and send text of byte values (eg: "FF-A0-17-AF-BC" etc), read next 50kb to send. So on until all bytes are read. The receiving side can combine those byte values into whole file (you code such an app, or they paste into some hex editor).

Answer (score 3):

This is the second thing today I have found something to be true that I thought wasn't possible. I took a small MP4 video file (86KB) and then encoded it into a data URI base 64 on this [site](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php). I made a simple test page of a `<video>` element with it's src attribute set:

```
`src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlzb21pc28yYXZj....
```

So a string of text can be a video, although I couldn't find a 50KB video file readily on my drive, I believe 86KB file size is sufficient proof. You can see it on this [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nK4trpyRhgB4bETbr3kU?p=preview)

Found this from this [article](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-image-data-uri-javascript):

```
function getDataUri(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image();

image.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    // Get raw image data
                                                       callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));

    // ... or get as Data URI
    callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
};

image.src = url;
```

}

```
// Usage
 getDataUri('/logo.png', function(dataUri) {
// Do whatever you'd like with the Data URI!
 });

You can modify this script to use videos instead of images.
```

Comment: Thanks for your rply Zer00ne . but i had already converted a image into a string  as in question i had given the code.Actually i don't know  how to do same thing for video. and i want complete video converted into string format (without playing/canvas element).

Comment: Hi @vimalraturi, I converted my video into a string, but it was with an online tool not JavaScript. I'm pretty sure this can be done with a server-side language like Python. It wouldn't be surprising to find a solution with JS though, maybe Node?