# clever way to convert video frames into txt

Tags: video, text

what could be a clever way to convert a video into text.
say that I record a screen where I scroll some text. how could I convert it into a text file from the mp4 file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert video file to string using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692933/how-to-convert-video-file-to-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this question is a bit vague but ill try my best to answer. To make your question less vague, ill answer the 2 questions which are 2 possible interpretations:

1. If you have a video and want to translate the **video into text** which can then be decoded and opened up to view as a video then no, I dont believe that exists. I could be wrong though. A more brute force way that I just found would be to use python where you grab a frame of the video and convert the frame into a '.bin' file which can also be decoded in python. I saw this guy do it on youtube and it seemed to work. https://youtu.be/TXXu1BVpjcg - To do this for a whole video, it would seem reasonable to use the code from the video in a while loop or something that iterates over every frame. Although its not a straight answer for 'video to text', this is a possible route you could try.
2. If you have a video and want to translate the **video audio to text** then you could use a service like https://www.transcribeme.com or https://www.veed.io/tools/video-to-text to do this. There are plenty transcription services all over the internet but I these were top results on google.

Answer (score 0):

You would take the video and split into frames. Save the all the frames as images. Read the text from all images and paste it in a text document.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).